# Как подключить autoplay к слайдеру?

Tags: javascript

есть слайдер к которому нужно подключить autoplay. Поискал ответы в интернете, не один не помог, а чтобы написать самому скрипт знаний маловато. Буду рад за помощь. Вот сам скрипт

```js
<script>
 $('._slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  centerPadding: '0px',
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  centerMode: true,
  responsive: [
   {
   breakpoint: 768,
   settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
   }
   },
  {
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
   slidesToShow: 2,
   slidesToScroll: 2
  }
  }
  ]

 });
</script>
```

Comment: Документация для лохов, ruSO для пацанов...

Answer (score 0):

Свойство autoplay  Пример

`$('.autoplay').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});`

Comment: Не работает, 
<script>
$('._slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
</script>

Comment: Убедись, что подключаешь библиотеку слайдера, после jQuery, а код инициализации скрипта после загрузки библиотеки. Убедись что правильно вызываешь нужный класс. Собственно, вот <code>  < a href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/"> документация к данному слайдеру </a> </code>

Comment: Все подключил, все правильно, но autoplay не заработал